# Fortran WRITE Not Writing

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have just added the following section of code to a model built on Fortran. I was told the write statement would print to a file named fort.70 on the local terminal in which the code is compiled and run, but no such file is created. Would anyone be able to point out what is causing this issue and how to solve it? Thank you in advance!

```
  YSTART = 2020
  YEND = 2100
  DO IYEAR = NYSTART, 351
      RI = (YEND-(1749+IYEAR))/(YEND-YSTART)
      IF (IYEAR .LT. YSTART) RI = 1.0
      IF (IYEAR .GT. YEND)  RI = 0.0
      WRITE (UNIT=70, FMT=*) IYEAR, RI
      DO ISPECY = 1, NTRMAX
          EMISSIONS(IYEAR, ISPECY) = RI*EMISSIONS(IYEAR, ISPECY)
      END DO
  END DO
```

Comment: No. You do not provide information as to why you expect this line of code to be executed. There are two questions: 1. is the `WRITE (UNIT=70, FMT=*) IYEAR, RI` executed? 2. If so, what compiler do you use? I am not sure that it is part of the standard what happens to un-opened Fortran file units.

Comment: It may be helpful to add the answers to the following into your question: When you say "I was told", who (or what) told you this? Where exactly are you expecting the file to be created and how are you running the code?

Comment: Also, this is not really an answer to your question, but it is better practice to explicitly open and close file connections in your code. That way you shouldn't have this problem (or any other side-effects) from hoping to implicitly open a file connection (and subsequently not closing it).

Comment: of course if there was already a unit 70 open your write will go to that file.

Comment: From experience, at least gfortran will behave as the poster wrote.

Comment: I'll try to answer each question here (thanks for the help by the way!) 1. That line of code (WRITE (UNIT=70, FMT=*) IYEAR, RI) is executed. 2. The compiler is GCC 6.1.0. 3. I was told to do this by my supervisor in a climate research unit. I do these operations remotely on our computing cluster at the university, and wish to create the file in a directory in that location. 4. I will look into explicitly opening a unit 70 for writing, thank you.

Comment: Ifort 13 also produces a fort.70 file. Where is NYSTART and is that different from YSTART

Comment: If the WRITE statement runs then it must be writing to somewhere, it is possible you just haven't found where. You could try an [INQUIRE](http://www.lahey.com/docs/lfenthelp/F95ARINQUIREStmt.htm) statement to find out a bit more about UNIT=70, writing the output to the console or to debug.